maui - Regarding errors after starting the app with Deep Link
After starting an app developed with .net MAUI using Deep Link, unexpected operations ([★1]) or errors ([★2]) may occur if you perform the operations described below.
[★1]：The camera screen should be displayed, but the page will change.
[★2]：An error 「App keeps stopping」 will occur (message will be displayed).
        ※App=Application name（In the case of the source for phenomenon confirmation, it is 「androidTEST」.）
※For details on the phenomenon and how to check it, please refer to the operations below.
※For log information, please refer to  below.
The source for confirming the phenomenon is below.
https://github.com/so-yamagiwa/android20241224
<Operation>

Close the app completely.
(Ensure it is not running in the background either.)
Launch the app with Deep Link.
※I prepared the HTML file described below and started the app.
※The phenomenon could not be confirmed when starting the app from the home screen.
Tap the 「Login」 button on 『LoginPage』.
（Move to 『MenuPage』.）
Tap the 「CapturePhoto」 button on 『MenuPage』 to start the camera.
（Move to 『PhotoPage』 . And the camera will start.）
Tap the smartphone home button to. go to the smartphone home screen.
Tap the app icon displayed on your smartphone to start the app.
（The camera screen is displayed.）
Repeat steps 5. and 6.
→The camera screen should normally be displayed,
but 『LoginPage』 is displayed instead. ([★1])
※In my environment, I was able to confirm [★1] after repeating it about two times.
After confirming [★1], performing steps 3 to 7 as they are will cause an error. ([★2])

※HTML content
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HTML page with links</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTML page with links</h1>
    <p>[androidtest]app StartUp：</p>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="androidtest://localhost/dplnkparam?userid=ADMINISTRATOR" target="_blank">androidTEST</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>

As this is my first time using .NET MAUI and creating an app,
I am not sure if there are any necessary processes that need to be done.
It is unknown what will happen on iOS when similar operations are performed.
(There is no testing environment.)
I am not proficient in English, so I am asking the questions using the translated content as it is.
Please let comment if any expressions are unclear.
<About logs>
Since I didn't know how to start debugging with Deep Link,
I couldn't check the error logs in Visual Studio.
※I executed the 'adb logcat' command to output the logs, but I couldn't understand the contents of the logs...
<About the test environment>
・VisualStudio2022
・.net MAUI8
・Android emulator（Android 15.0 API35）
Please tell me why the phenomena [★1] and [★2] occur when I perform the above operations, and how to avoid them.
